# How to insert image in HTML in python script?

Tags: python, html

I am writing a htmlfunction in python as below:

```py
def html(function):
    htmlfile = open(function.name+".html", "w")
    htmlfile.write("<html>\n")
    # statement for title
    # statement for header
    htmlfile.write('<img src = '+function.name+'.png alt ="cfg">\n') 
    htmlfile.write("</html>\n")
    htmlfile.close()
```

earlier I had files in the same directory where I am running my script. Now I have created a folder images for it and all moved files to this folder. `function.name+` pulls up different functions name
how to change img src line? when I substitute `images/'function.name+'`, the image doesn't get inserted to HTML.

All images have name in the format

```
<name of the function>.png
```

Comment: htmlfile.write ('<img src = "'+function.name+'.png" alt ="cfg">\n')

Comment: Looks like you forgot quotes around the `src` attribute.

Comment: Try: `'<img src = "{}.png" alt = "cfg">\n'.format(function.name)`

Comment: @heinst : thanks for correction. Basically when I run my script png file gets generated and i insert it to html. earlier it used to be in the same directory as script run directory. now i have created a folder to keep all png files and trying to call it from that folder. I am writing images/+function.name+.png, but it doesn't show image on html page

Comment: @geek_xed since its in a different directory you want to do `htmlfile.write ('<img src = "nameOfDirectory/"'+function.name+'.png" alt ="cfg">\n')`

Comment: yes for this I am doing as below: script_path = os.path.dir_name (os.path.abspath(___file___)) and then image_path = os.path.join(script_path, linuxmachine, function.name + ".png") , then finally htmlfile.write('<img src = image_path alt ="cfg">\n"). Still it is not working.

Comment: @geek_xed try `htmlfile.write('<img src = "' + image_path + '" alt ="cfg">\n')`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it as below:

```py
from robot.api import logger

img = "example.jpg"
strImg = '"{}"'.format(img)

img_tag = "<img src=" + strImg + ">"
logger.info(img_tag, html=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think this works. The image does get inserted to HTML.

```
def html(function):
    htmlfile = open(function.name+".html", "w")
    htmlfile.write("<html>\n")
    statement for title
    statement for header
    htmlfile.write('<img src = "' + image_path + '" alt ="cfg">\n')
    htmlfile.write("</html>\n")
    htmlfile.close()
```